# C# generics,where does GetProcesses comes from?

Tags: c#

I am looking at this example from LINQ In Action book.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;

static class LanguageFeatures
{
  static void DisplayProcesses()
  {
  List<String> processes = new List<String>();
  foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcesses())
    processes.Add(process.ProcessName);
    ObjectDumper.Write(processes);
  } 


  static void Main()
  {
    DisplayProcesses();
  }
}
```

I understand that List class has ForEach method,but I can not grasp how GetProcesses are recognized by compiler.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: `GetProcesses` has nothing to do with generics. It's a static method on the `Process` class. I'm not sure where your confusion comes from (nor what you're trying to say about `ForEach`)

Comment: That's `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses()` static method.

Comment: `System.Diagnostics` defines a class called `Process`, which has a static method `GetProcesses()`, which returns a list of running processes. You have included a `using` statement for System.Diagnostics. What is there to get?

Comment: just like how `Console.WriteLine` is recognized

Comment: @john Yes,that was the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are thinking of this as user defined method, however, this method is the member of the `Process` class of System.Diagnostics dll

https://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/1f3ys1f9(v=vs.110).aspx

> Use this method to create an array of new Process components and associate them with all the process resources on the local computer.

Answer (score 2):

The .NET framework has a bunch of prebuilt classes (like Systems.Diagnostics.Process) which are wrappers over OS functionality, and give you this information. Not in any way related to generics.

The author of the book used this static class method for convenience to get a collection of items in order to demonstrate LINQ functionality.